# Populate php email body with div content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to send an email using php where the email body is populated by the contents of an html table. I am getting no errors on console but the data is not importing. Any ideas on what I am missing?

email.php -

```
$admin = "sender@email.com";
$email = "recipient@email.com";
$subject = "Alert Activated";
$body = $_POST['content'];

mail($admin, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email, $body);
```

AJAX-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.export').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'email.php',
     data: { content: $('#realparts-data').html()}
        });
    });

    });
```

Comment: Add the `success` part of the ajax call and `console.log` the results of it. What do you get?

Comment: Madae an edit... The email is sent. Console.log is empty because the data is not being populated.

Comment: Add `var_dump($body);` to your php then look in your console to see if you get anything.